# Update last seen of User - CodeIgniter4

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller, codeigniter-4

I have my application almost ready. And I have created `is_loggedin()` helper to check whether the User is logged in or not, so that I could do conditional display of data.

Right now, am trying to update the `last_seen` of an User. I have this field in database for each User record.

I can manually add the code to update the database under each method of my controllers (where the views are rendered). But since there is `BaseController` that we inherit, how can this be done in a single place. As this is a common feature.

Idea is like this:

> user visits any page
>
> > check if User is logged in
> >
> > > if logged in user, update the last_seen

Comment: May be updating the login function with this may help.

Comment: You can force some hooks in CodeIgniter by using FILTERS: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/incoming/filters.html